# How to escape shell parameter such as '-n'

Tags: shell, echo

How to escape special character? I want to print minus character.

```
echo \-; # Output:-
echo '-n'; #Output: nothing!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to print `-n` which is interpreted as an argument to disable printing of the trailing newline.

Here `printf` comes handy:

```
$ printf "%s" "-n"
-n
```

If you want a newline after `n`,

```
$ printf "%s\n" "-n"
-n
```

An *ugly* way using `echo` would be to use the octal value for the hyphen, i.e. `-`,

```
$ echo -e '\055n'
-n
```

The `-e` argument enables interpretation of backslash escapes.

Comment: The `printf` statement with a newline is the most equivalent to `echo`

Comment: @Stijn If that is the case, it seems rather odd.  Consider renaming it to _oracle-server_ or so.  I'm sure that the tag would attract a lot of spam.

Comment: Cool! Then echo also support Hex `echo '\x31'`.

Comment: @hilojack Yes, it does.